# Github Actions publish to Github Package registry fails with 401 using GITHUB_TOKEN (suddenly)

Tags: c#, .net-core, github-actions, github-package-registry

a Github Actions workflow stopped working throwing a 401 error when publishing a repo's package to the Github package registry. Within the workflow (detailed below) I am using `semantic-release` to publish the artefact to the registry. This is the last step in the yml. The permissions for the GITHUB_TOKEN have not been changed since initial setup of the action. It used to run just fine with these permissions.

./github/workflow.yml

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, dev ]
    paths: 
      - src/**

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      packages: write
      issues: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.x.x'

      - name: Build that shit
        run: dotnet build ./src/project.csproj --configuration Release --nologo

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 'lts/*'

      - name: Release that shit
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: npm ci && npx semantic-release
```

The `GITHUB_TOKEN` is mapped to an environment variable `GH_TOKEN` which then is referenced by `semantic-release` in the `publishCmd`.

./.releaserc

```json
{
  "branches": [
    "main",
    {
      "name": "dev",
      "prerelease": "dev"
    }
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/github",
    [
      "@semantic-release/exec", {
        "prepareCmd": "dotnet pack ./src/project.csproj --no-restore --nologo --configuration Release /p:Version=${nextRelease.version}",
        "publishCmd": "dotnet nuget push ./src/bin/Release/project.${nextRelease.version}.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ORG/index.json --api-key ${process.env.GH_TOKEN}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The logs show the last step failing

```
[11:05:13 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "publish" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[11:05:13 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/exec] › ℹ  Call script dotnet nuget push ./src/bin/Release/project.2.8.6.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ORG/index.json --api-key [secure]
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ORG/index.json.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

This is a repo owned by the *organization* I am employed with. There are no dependencies to private packages registries, only public NUGET. So the GITHUB_TOKEN should suffice [according to the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#:%7E:text=GITHUB_TOKEN%20to%20publish%20packages%20associated%20with%20the%20workflow%20repository.). And also according to previous successful execution history.

Does someone spot something I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a nuget.config in the root?

Comment: No I don't. But this used to work until recently even without it.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using [`dotnet nuget push`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-release.yml#L45)? Note that [`nuget.exe push`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-release.yml#L48) for the github registry respects te `SkipDuplicate` flag

Comment: I also had to add the [`source-url`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-release.yml#L23) in the `setup-dotnet` step

Comment: I am, `dotnet nuget push ./src/bin/Release/project.2.8.6.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY_ORG/index.json --api-key GITHUB_TOKEN`. In abence of nuget.config and a --source param, wouldn't that that command result into a publish attempt ti public nuget?

Comment: Thanks for the hint with source-url. Although, when I read [this](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet#setting-up-authentication-for-nuget-feeds:~:text=source%2Durl%3A%20https%3A//nuget.pkg.github.com/%3Cowner%3E/index.json) correctly, the source-url is relevant if you're installing dependencies from Github. I only use public Nuget dependencies, so this should not be required, should it?

Comment: [Here's an entire discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/26906) I had with sir Jamie Cansdale, which eventually lead me to the [workflow I'm using today](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-release.yml). I had to use `nuget.exe push` (which is provided by `setup-msbuild`) because I was building multi-target packages containing 4 dll's, and the package was too large for the step to succeed. But `nuget.exe push` also fixes the issue where `--skip-duplicate` is ignored

Comment: And [here's the discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/24915) where it appears that large packages should be pushed using `nuget.exe push`

Comment: Note that I'm using `-NoSymbols` since github doesn't host a symbol server

Comment: This also stopped working for me today in a repo that was working fine. I did a minor change (one package upgrade) and GH actions doesn't work anymore with ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
Other repos are working fin though. Desisted and pushed manually from my machine, hoping it will work again

Comment: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/38782

Comment: My packages are small ~40Kb, single dlls, built on ubuntu, net 7, something just stopped working

Answer (score 0):

The only way I made this work again on GH is using a PAT.

Created a PAT in my user/developer settings

Added a secret in my repo called `NUGET_PAT`

Updated my yaml file to this

```
name: "Push to main"

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  publish:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:     
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '7.0.x'
      
      - name: Add source
        run: |
          dotnet nuget add source \
             --username THE_USER_OWNER_OF_THE_PAT --password "${{ secrets.NUGET_PAT }}" \
             --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/YOUR_ORG/index.json"

      - name: Restore packages
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release -p:Version=${{github.ref_name}} --no-restore

      - name: Run tests
        run: dotnet test --configuration Release --no-restore --no-build --verbosity normal
        
      - name: Create nuget packages
        run: dotnet pack --configuration Release -p:Version=${{github.ref_name}} --no-restore --no-build

      - name: Publish nuget packages
        run: dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg -s "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/YOUR_ORG/index.json"
```

It pushes with warnings

Comment: Thanks. PATs didn't work for me yesterday either in GH actions. They did locally. The link you have provided above in the comments to my original question solved the problem for me. 2 hours ago, someone there suggested to remove the index.json  from the --source. I just did this and the package pushed successfully to the github registry.

Comment: The same linked discussion above indicates, that the original behaviour should be working again